# Finding $\left(\bigcup _{i=1}^4 A_i\right)^c , \left(\bigcap_{i=1}^4 A_i\right)^c=\overset{4} \bigcup \limits_{i=1} A{_i}^c$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\Gamma$={1, 2, 3, 4} and and $A_1$={a, b, c, d}, $A_2$={b, c, d}, $A_3$={a, b, c}, $A_4=\{a, b\}$. Then

(a)  $\overset 4 \bigcup \limits_{i=1}A_i$ =$A{_1} \bigcup A{_2} \bigcup A{_3} \bigcup A{_4}$={a, b, c, d}

(b)  $\overset 4 \bigcap \limits_{i=1}A_i$ = $A{_1} \bigcap A{_2} \bigcap A{_3} \bigcap A{_4}$={b}

Now, can we also find $x \in (\overset{4} \bigcup \limits_{i=1} A_i)^c$ and $x \in (\overset{4} \bigcap \limits_{i=1} A_i)^c$ if we let the universal set U={a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}?

If so, is my answer for my another curiosity also correct?

$(\overset{4} \bigcup \limits_{i=1} A_i)^c$ 
=$\overset{4} \bigcap \limits_{i=1} A{_i}^c$ = $A{_1}^c \bigcap A{_2}^c \bigcap A{_3}^c \bigcap A{_4}^c$ ={e, f, g, h, i}

$(\overset{4} \bigcap \limits_{i=1} A_i)^c$=$\overset{4} \bigcup \limits_{i=1} A{_i}^c$ = $A{_1}^c \bigcup A{_2}^c \bigcup A{_3}^c \bigcup A{_4}^c$ ={a, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}

FYI 
"Theorem 8 The Generalized De Morgan's Theorem

Let {$A_r$|$r\in\Gamma$} be an arbitrary family of sets. Then

(a) $(\bigcup\limits_{r\in\Gamma}A_r)^c=\bigcap\limits_{r\in\Gamma}A_r^c$

(b) $(\bigcap\limits_{r\in\Gamma}A_r)^c=\bigcup\limits_{r\in\Gamma}A_r^c$"

"
Theorem 6 De Morgan's Theorem

For any two sets A and B,

(a) $(A\bigcup B)^c$= $A^c \bigcap B^c$
(b) $(A\bigcap B)^c$ = $A^c \bigcup B^c$
"

Comment: For future reference, you can write for example $\displaystyle\bigcap_{i=1}^4 A_i$ as `\bigcap_{i=1}^4 A_i`, and $\{a,b,c,d\}$ as `\{a,b,c,d\}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your application of De Morgan's laws are correct. As a check, you showed that
$$
A=  \,\overset 4 \bigcup \limits_{i=1}A_i =A{_1} \bigcup A{_2} \bigcup A{_3} \bigcup A{_4}=\{a, b, c, d\} $$
and
$$
B=  \,\overset 4 \bigcap \limits_{i=1}A_i = A{_1} \bigcap A{_2} \bigcap A{_3} \bigcap A{_4}=\{b\} .
$$
Well the complement of $A$ is $U\setminus A = \{e,f,g,h,i\}$.
The complement of $B$ is $U\setminus B = \{a,c,d,e,f,g,h,i\}.$
This agrees with what you showed.